# Using __in for a custom query in django-filters

Tags: django-filter

I'm using django-filters 1.1.0.  I need to write a filter that uses a custom query but in which it can optionally take an `__in` suffix.

This is my solution, but I can't help hope that there is a slightly cleaner way of doing this similar to how `id` is specified -- perhaps using a single method for bar and `'exact'` or `'__in'` being passed in as a lookup arg.

```
class FooFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    bar_id = filters.CharFilter(method='filter_bar_id', label='Bar')
    bar_id__in = filters.CharFilter(method='filter_bar_id__in', label='Bar In')


    def filter_bar_id(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(
            Q(abc__xyz__bar=value) |
            Q(def__xyz__bar=value)).distinct()

    def filter_bar_id__in(self, queryset, name, value):
        bars = value.split(',')
        return queryset.filter(
            Q(abc__xyz__bar__in=bars) |
            Q(def__xyz__bar__in=bars)).distinct()

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = {
            'id': ['exact', 'in'],
            'bar_id': ['exact'],
            'bar_id__in': ['exact'],
        }
```

Does django-filters have a way to do this more natively?  Or is this pretty much the way to accomplish this?

There is another stackoverflow question that uses `bar_id=` to allow both `?bar_id=1` and `?bar_id=1,2,3,4`.  For consistency's sake with the rest of my django-filters (like `?id` and `?id__in`, I am not interested in doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage `BaseInFilter`'s validation logic, which will convert a comma-separated input value into a list of values. From there, your custom filter method could switch based on the type of the value.

That said, I don't think that this solution is necessarily superior to what you currently have. Also, this won't generally work with additional lookup expressions. In this case, you only happen to be able to switch on type.

```py
class CharListFilter(filters.BaseInFilter, filters.CharFilter):
    pass


class FooFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    bar_id = filters.CharFilter(method='filter_bar_id', label='Bar')
    bar_id__in = filters.CharListFilter(method='filter_bar_id', label='Bar In')

    def filter_bar_id(self, queryset, name, value):
        if isinstance(value, list):
            return queryset.filter(
                Q(abc__xyz__bar__in=value) |
                Q(def__xyz__bar__in=value)).distinct()
        return queryset.filter(
            Q(abc__xyz__bar=value) |
            Q(def__xyz__bar=value)).distinct()
```